# Swing create theme class

Tags: java, swing

I am developing custom **Swing components** (`JButton, Container, JComponent`) and would like to provide theming for these.

So I would create a `"Theme"` class which the user would implement to set the color and shapes of the items. All the components that are added the the container will automatically follow this theme.

> For example the user would specify in the `Theme` class that the components including the window itself should be a rhombus shape. The colors red,blue,green should also be used.

The problem is, I am really unsure how I should develop this `"Theme"` class.
Any advice is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Look at ComponentUI and UIManager

Comment: `the user would specify in the Theme class that the components including the window itself should be a rhombus shape` - basically you need to rewrite Swing. Swing is designed for rectangles, not any other shape.